# T-SQL recursion using table variable for intermediate results?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursion

I have a tricky logic problem involving some form of recursion that I need help with.

Slightly simplified, imagine that there is a table containing pairs of `IDs` (`AID` and `BID` - both `int`) of rows in another table that are to be considered synonyms (the order of `ID`s in each pair is not significant). What I want to do is for any supplied `ID` to return a (`distinct`) set of all `ID`s that are synonyms of that `ID` or are synonyms of any synonym of that `ID`, and so on, up to an arbitrary number of 'levels' (there needs to be such a limit to prevent infinite looping - i.e. where 1-2, 2-3, 3-1). For example, given the following rows:

```
1,2
1,3
1,4
5,1
2,6
2,7
3,8
3,9
4,10
```

then for `ID = 5` I would expect `1-4` and `6-10` to be returned.

I have tried calling a recursive table-based function with a table variable to hold intermediate results and using a cursor to iterate through the records in the table variable, but the results are incomplete for reasons that are not clear (although I suspect that I need to find a way of reinitialising the cursor after adding any rows to the table variable). But I suspect that the whole approach is flawed (which is why I have not given my existing code) and would be grateful if anyone has a better suggestion or has tried something similar.

Comment: You can do this with a recursive CTE, you'll just have to carry along of for example a string that contains all the IDs you have already checked so that there's no endless loops

Comment: Something similar as in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31491265/4420967 That was for counting the distance of friendships so it's slightly more complex but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two approaches. The first uses a CTE that is quite inefficient. The problem is that during recursion you cannot examine all of the other rows in the result set. While you can build a list of the rows that have contributed to a given row, you cannot check to see if you already reached that row via another path. The second approach uses a loop to populate a table with relations one step at a time. It is a much better method than the CTE.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @RecursiveTable as Table ( AId Int, BId Int );
insert into @RecursiveTable ( AId, BId ) values
  ( 1, 2 ), ( 1, 3 ), ( 1, 4 ),
  ( 5, 1 ),
  ( 2, 6 ), ( 2, 7 ),
  ( 3, 8 ), ( 3, 9 ),
  ( 4, 10 );
select * from @RecursiveTable;

-- Walk the tree with a recursive CTE.
--   NB: This is woefully inefficient since we cannot promptly detect
--   rows that have already been processed.
declare @Start as Int = 5;
with Pairs as (
  select AId, BId, Cast( AId as VarChar(10) ) + '/' + Cast( BId as VarChar(10) ) as Pair
    from @RecursiveTable ),
 Relations as (
  select AId, BId, Cast( '|' + Pair + '|' as VarChar(1024) ) as Path
    from Pairs
    where AId = @Start or BId = @Start
  union all
  select P.AId, P.BId, Cast( R.Path + P.Pair + '|' as VarChar(1024) )
    from Relations as R inner join
      Pairs as P on P.BId = R.AId or P.AId = R.BId or
        P.BId = R.BId or P.AId = R.AId
    where CharIndex( '|' + P.Pair + '|', R.Path ) = 0
  )
  -- To see how terrible this is, try: select * from Relations
  select AId as Id
    from Relations
    where AId <> @Start
  union
  select BId
    from Relations
    where BId <> @Start
    order by Id;

-- Try again using a loop to add relations to a working table.
declare @Relations as Table ( AId Int, BId Int );
insert into @Relations
  select AId, BId
    from @RecursiveTable
    where AId = @Start or BId = @Start;
while @@RowCount > 0
  insert into @Relations
    select RT.AId, RT.BId
      from @Relations as R inner join
        @RecursiveTable as RT on RT.BId = R.BId or RT.AId = R.AId or
          RT.BId = R.AId or RT.AId = R.BId
    except
    select AId, BId
      from @Relations;
select AId as Id
  from @Relations
  where AId <> @Start
union
  select BId
  from @Relations
  where BId <> @Start
  order by Id;
```

Comment: I had already gone down the recursive CTE route and did in fact get it to do what I want, albeit a little slowly - as you say it is not possible to detect duplicate 'routes' during the recursion. The loop approach looks interesting but so far for me does not terminate - clearly I need to limit the levels of 'recursion' to trap continuous 'loops' in the data, but it is not obvious to me how to do this using this approach. But many thanks for your response and I'll keep working on it.

Comment: @JonStranger - Do you have a small data set that causes a non-terminating loop? I did try a few looping entries before posting the answer and all terminated promptly with correct results.

Answer (score 0):

It's an odd problem, but try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fSynonyms(@val Int, @maxRecursions Int)
  RETURNS @ret TABLE
  (
     num    Int
  )
AS BEGIN 
  DECLARE @Values TABLE ( num Int )
  INSERT INTO @Values VALUES(@val)
  DECLARE @i Int = 0

  WHILE @i < @maxRecursions
  BEGIN
     INSERT INTO VAL
       SELECT aid 
       FROM @Values VAL
            INNER JOIN Aliases ALIAS
               ON ALIAS.bid = VAL.num

     INSERT INTO VAL
        SELECT bid
         FROM @Values VAL
              INNER JOIN Aliases ALIAS
                ON ALIAS.aid = VAL.num

     SET @i += 1
   END

   INSERT INTO @Ret
      SELECT DISTINCT num FROM @Values

    RETURN
END
```

You can join against the output of this function, which would include all defined alias values for the given value, up to the designated recursion depth.

I feel confident that, following this approach, you can get rid of the cursor.